# What is the difference

Tags: differences

What is the difference between :
1- He was working.
2- He has been working.

I am confused.

Comment: It would need context, but the first may suggest he is not working now

Answer (score -1):

1. "He was working" means, He started to a work before and he left the job or something. So he is not working at the moment.
2. "He has been working" means,  You started to work a job before and you are working at the moment.

Present perfect tense has generally two meanings:

a. The action started before and continue now.

--He has been living in this town  since he was born. (he is still  living in the town)

b.The action started before and continue its effects at the moment.

--He has had a car accident. (that's why he is in the hospital)

--I have already eaten the dinner. (so I'm not hungry)

--He has finished his work. (so he can now rest)

Comment: Neither the *simple past* tense nor the *present perfect continuous* tense say whether or not the action has finished.

Comment: Actually, gramatically what I said is true above. We can understand the meaning of the action from context.